# Wrapping Origen::Parameters define_params method

Tags: origen-sdk

I would like to wrap the [define_params method](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/api/Origen/Parameters.html#define_params-instance_method) so the user can pass in an `array` versus a `symbol`, so binning configuration can be setup for multiple test insertions at once :

```
scan.define_binning [:ws1, :ws2] do |config|
  config.chain.softbin = 'bbxxx'
  config.chain.bin =     16      
  config.logic.softbin = 'bbxxx'
  config.logic.bin =     5 
end
```

How would you wrap around the `define_params` method?

Thanks!

Comment: thx for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be as well submitting an update to Origen to make `define_params` accept an array of parameter names, but to answer the question (note this is untested):

```rb
def define_binning(names, options = {}, &block)
  Array(names).each do |name|
    define_params(name, options.dup, &block)
  end
end
```

That forces names to an array, then for each name it calls the `define_params` method with the same options/block.

`options.dup` is used in case the underlying method does something like `options.delete(:blah)` and this ensures that each call definitely gets the same set of options passed to it.

Comment: is there a way to get the method alias without having to put a bunch of alias_method calls?  Essentially i want to delegate from my method to the define_params method.  This would be easy with an instance method but not sure how it works in this case.

Comment: This is an instance method, not sure what you mean

Comment: Edited the answer which may help, I didn't catch the first time around that you wanted to make a method called `define_binning`